# How to set path to `gfortran` in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, fortran, gfortran

A colleague got a new mac, and he codes with Eclipse and gfortran. And Makefiles. But now he cannot build.

I figured that Eclipse does not use the same PATH as shell, so while Eclipse is happy to build with a makefile, it cannot find `gfortran`. (The Makefile works fine when ran form the mac terminal.)

Eclipse *can* build, if I put the full path in the Makefile (`FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran`). But this is extra nuisance when other people use Ubuntu where `gfortran` has a different path.

**Question:** How/where to configure Eclipse (Juno) so that it can find `gfortran`? (I could not find, I tried.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Photran.  It is based on Eclipse and is set up for Fortran.